# SwiftUI show List of Dates from Core Data

Tags: swift, date, swiftui, core-data

I try to show the time from in Core Data saved Dates in a List, but it isn't showing anything in the rows of the List. But it creates one row for every entry in Core Data.

```
struct TopBoxView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var newFlaschen
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors:  []) var flasche: FetchedResults<Flasche>
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    
    var body: some View {
        GroupBox() {
            
            VStack {
                
                Text("Letzte Flaschen")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.system(size: 28, weight: .medium, design: .default))
                    .padding(.top, 25)
                
                List(flasche) { flaschen in //here it should create the List
                    Text("\(flaschen.zeit ?? "nix")")
                        .listRowBackground(Color("listRowColor"))
                }
                .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                .padding(.horizontal, 13.0)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                
                _VSpacer()
                    .frame(height: 10)
            }
        }
        .groupBoxStyle(GroupBoxStandardStyle(width: 290))
        .padding(.top, 10)
        .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
    }
}
```

At the Moment the dates are already saved as Strings in CoreData:

```
struct BottomBoxView: View {
    
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    
    @State var menge = ""
    @State var time = Date.now
    @State var anmerkungen = ""
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var newFlasche
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors:  []) var flasche: FetchedResults<Flasche>
    
    func submit() {
        let neueFlasche = Flasche(context: newFlasche)
        let formattedTime = dateFormatter.string(from: time)
        
        neueFlasche.id = UUID()
        neueFlasche.menge = menge
        neueFlasche.zeit = formattedTime
        neueFlasche.anmerkungen = anmerkungen
        
        try? newFlasche.save()
    }
```

the function is called by a button
I should add, that when i try to show another String, that is created as a string, not as a Date, it shows it without problems.

I tried .formatted and i tried to save it as a string

I don't know what i did different to some of my previous tries, but now I have the Time saved as a Date and with this code I show it:

```
                List(flasche) { flasche in
                    Text((flasche.zeit?.formatted() ?? "none"))
                        .listRowBackground(Color("listRowColor"))
                }
```

Thank you, for your Help!

Comment: Unrelated but why not store the date as a Date?

Comment: The Problem is, that i don‘g know how to show them. The Text View only shows Strings

Comment: Eh, you use a date formatter of course. Now there is even a new type of date formatting in SwiftUI so you can display it as `Text(flaschen.zeit.formatted())` without having to use a specific formatter object.

Comment: Another hint: If you create a new Flasche object, you should add the Date() there. If you preserve it as a @State var, it will not change when submit() is called, which I assume you want though.